# vcpkg: code execution cannot proceed because dll was not found

Tags: visual-studio, build, msbuild, vcpkg

[image]

I installed protobuf with vcpkg.

This happens when I build/redeploy and no c++ files where changed (i.e. no c++ linking). Changes in Xaml, and hlsl files for example.

I can fix this by touching any c++ file and rebuilding, but this is ruining my DX.

I have been naively copying the dll to the build output but this has just stopped working. I think the execute after/execute before default options changed may have changed in visual studio.

### Steps to reproduce

Install protobuf with vcpkg (also have vcpkg integrated with vs)

Generate `.h` and `.cpp` files using the protobuf compiler `vcpkg\packages\protobuf_x64-windows\tools\protobuf\protoc.exe` https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/cpptutorial/

Include them in a project created with the `Blank App WinUI 3 c++` template.

### Can someone help me set up a build command to copy the dll across after everything else has finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a `post-build` event! so in visual studio right click on your project and select `Properties`,then in `Build Events` tab, select `Post-Build Event` section and enter the command to copy the DLL file to the desired output directory!

something like this :

```
xcopy /y "$(PathToDLL)\protobuf.dll" "$(TargetDir)"
```

***don't forget to replace `$(PathToDLL)\protobuf.dll` and `$(TargetDir)` with the actual path!!!***

now save the project properties, and that's it.

good luck !

Comment: Turns out that the files were in "$(OutDir)", but they need to be in ""$(OutDir)AppX"